# HTC HD2 Windows Mobile Suppress "NO SIM card Message"

Tags: windows-mobile, htc-android

I am running a WM 6.5 application on the HTC HD2 device in kiosk mode.  When the phone is turned on and there is no SIM card, a system message is displayed telling the user the SIM Card is missing and you can only make emergency calls.  Does anybody know if this message can be turned off or how to suppress it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two posible solutions/workarounds:

1. Shut down the WWAN Radio (see wireless manager or by using a custom app)
2. Replace cprog.exe with a dummy exe. This would disable all phone activities.

AFAIK there is no setting to just suppress the popup.

Comment: Replacing cprog with a dummy app looks promising, as the user will not be making or receiving phone calls.  I assume this will not adversely affect the use of GPRS Connection in any way?

Comment: cprog is only for voice calls and dialogs but will not affect GPRS connections made from code. But if you will make GPRS connections, you need a SIM card and then the message "No SIM" will not show. So why should you then replace cprog?

Comment: I want to replace cprog in order to handle the SIM card missing error within our Kiosked app instead of having the phone message take over the entire screen.  The SIM card should always be there, but if a user removes it, we want to contain the error within our application.  Make sense?

Comment: For anybody interested, note that stubbing out the phone app may cause calls to SystemState.PhoneNoService to return true and Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Status.SystemState.PhoneOperatorName to return null.